# Problems with async task inside fragment

Tags: android, android-asynctask, fragment

I'm using async tasks to fetch data from server. The async task is called on the onCreate method of the fragment. But the result is always null when called from inside fragment.

This is the async task:

```
public class getDateEventsAsync extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        Log.v("getDateEvents","OK");
        InputStream input;

        try{
            URL url = new URL(ServerURL);

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();


            obj.put("action","getDateEvents");
            obj.put("date",mParam1);


            JSONArray x = new JSONArray(mParam2);
            obj.put("userDisciplinas",x);


            Log.d("Request-Events",obj.toString());



            ContentValues val = new ContentValues();
            val.put("rpc_message",obj.toString());


            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(val.toString());

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();

            conn.connect();
            int response = conn.getResponseCode();
            Log.e("Result", "" + response);

            StringBuilder sbuilder = new StringBuilder();

            if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                input = conn.getInputStream();
                String line;
                BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                while ((line = buf.readLine()) != null) {
                    sbuilder.append(line);
                }
                Log.e("Result", sbuilder.toString());
            }


            return sbuilder.toString();

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        try{
            events_array = new JSONArray(s);
            Log.e("Array",events_array.toString());
            RestartAdapter();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I call the async task from the activity as bellow, it works.

```
 Fragment frag = DayFragment.newInstance(day,new getDateEventsAsync().execute(day).get());
        //Fragment frag = DayFragment.newInstance(day,userModules_ids.toString());
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, frag,"DIA").addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

But if I load the fragment as the commented line, and use the async task from inside the fragment it doesn't work.

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: Never use `.execute().get()` with an AsyncTask. It defeats the purpose of making it **async**

Comment: Besides, AsyncTask and POST-ing JSON gets messy... Have you considered using Volley, OkHttp, or Retrofit?

Comment: I suggest anywhere you consume REST API's sending JSON, use any of the libraries mentioned by @cricket_007. Makes your life much easier, and in some situations executes faster http://instructure.github.io/blog/2013/12/09/volley-vs-retrofit/

Answer (score 0):

the purpose of using async task is to run codes in background but when you use .get() method ,your program will wait until async task complete the job !

try to run async task inside your fragment's onViewCreated or onResume

btw consider using third-party libraries like Volley or OkHttp or Retrofit for your network processes